# Deleting empty rows - MS Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using following VBA to delete all the rows that does not have * in Column T. It works but it only deletes 1 row at a time. I have to run the vba 25 times in order to delete 25 rows that does not have * in the column T. Do you see anything wrong with the code?

```
Sub DeleteCells()

    'Loop through cells A1:A10 and delete cells that contain an "x."
    For Each c In Range("t1:t35")
        If c <> "*" Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: deletion process requires to be run from last item to first. that is the reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For Each Next loop unexpectedly skipping some entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515692/for-each-next-loop-unexpectedly-skipping-some-entries)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete rows you should work from the bottom up rather than the top down:

```
Sub DeleteCells()
Dim i As Long

For i = 35 To 1 Step -1
    If Range("T" & i).Value <> "*" Then Range("T" & i).EntireRow.delete
Next i

End Sub
```

A more efficient way would be to use the autofilter and avoid looping all together.  Something like:

```
Sub DeleteCellsFilter()
    Sheet1.Range("$T$1:$T$35").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*"
    Sheet1.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.delete
    Sheet1.UsedRange.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

This makes a couple assumptions that you should correct:

1) We're interacting w/ Sheet1
2) Your range is static (rows 1 to 35).

You should adjust these assumptions as appropriate.

Comment: Works. Except I changed Range("T" & i).Value <> "*"

Comment: @torres great Glad it worked out for you.  Feel free to try the Filter method, as it's a lot more efficient.  Either way, if you think it's a good solid answer, please mark it as "accepted".  Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: + 1 For Auto Filter :)