# Delete blank row using For Next

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my code about delete blank rows. It just has to delete some rows not all blank rows and rows value "0". I don't wanna use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` as some threat on SO forum.

```
Dim R As Integer
R = Range("CuoiNKC").Row - 1
Dim DelCell As Range
Dim DelRange As Range
Set DelRange = Range("J9:J" & R)
For Each DelCell In DelRange
    If DelCell.Value = "0" Or DelCell.Formula = Space(0) Then
        DelCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next DelCel
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [For Each Next loop unexpectedly skipping some entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515692/for-each-next-loop-unexpectedly-skipping-some-entries)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `Range AutoFilter Method` instead of looping.
Assuming you have the correct value of `DelRange` in your code, try this:

```
DelRange.AutoFilter 1, AutoFilter 1, "=0", xlOr, "=" 'filtering 0 and space
DelRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete xlUp 'delete visible cells
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove auto filter mode
```

Btw, if you want to stick with your logic, you need to iterate the rows backward.
You can only do that using the conventional `For Next Loop`. Again assuming value of `R` is correct.

```
For i = R To 9 Step -1
    If Range("J" & i).Value = "0" Or Range("J" & i).Value = " " Then
        Range("J" & i).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This way as we record macro, I know this way too. But in my code I dont know why It's just delete some rows and do it again it continues delete much more but not all. With my code I want to solve more problem @L42

Comment: Thank you L42 and if I want to know how many row was deleted, how to do? (how many i was used)

Comment: @kobebryant Just add another counter variable inside the loop.