# Hi, I have blocks of blank rows in my excel sheet, to remove them i have used this code but it skips blank rows in between

Tags: excel, vba

```
For n = 1 To 99
    If IsEmpty(Cells(n, 1)) Then
        Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next n
```

This is the code i have used, but it skips blank rows i have an idea about reverse loops to avoid this but haven't done myself. please help me i am a newbie in excel.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [For Each Next loop unexpectedly skipping some entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515692/for-each-next-loop-unexpectedly-skipping-some-entries)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Sub ChkDis()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B1:B99")
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```