# Copy old emails in archive subfolder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

i have a code that copies the emails that are older than 2 days in an archive but if i want to copy the emails in an archive subfolder, it will not do the job. any help is welcomed.

```
Sub Copy_d_2()
Dim myOutlookFolders As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objSourceFolderMAIN As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objVariant As Variant
    Dim lngMovedItems As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim intDateDiff As Integer
    Dim strDestFolder As String

Dim a As Date
a = Now()
Dim b As String
b = Format(a, "mmmm")
Dim c As String
c = Format(a, "yyyy")
Dim nam As String
nam = "Archive me " & b & " " & c


    Set objNamespace = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objSourceFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - Share").Folders("Inbox").Folders("all emails")
    Set objSourceFolderMAIN = Session.Folders("Archive Folders")

    Set objDestFolder = Session.Folders("Archive Folders").Folders(nam).Folders("d2")

    For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
        DoEvents
        If objVariant.Class = olMail Then

             intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", objVariant.SentOn, Now)
             If intDateDiff > 2 Then
             objVariant.Copy objDestFolder
             lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1

            End If
        End If
    Next

Set objDestFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You still need help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something similar:
[How to move each emails from inbox to a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779782/how-to-move-each-emails-from-inbox-to-a-sub-folder)

However, concerning your code, I have played a little and managed to do this:

```
Sub Copy_d_2()

    Dim myOutlookFolders        As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objOutlook              As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace            As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objSourceFolder         As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objSourceFolderMAIN     As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objDestFolder           As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objVariant              As Variant
    Dim lngMovedItems           As Long
    Dim intCount                As Integer
    Dim intDateDiff             As Integer
    Dim strDestFolder           As String

    Dim a As Date
    a = Now()
    Dim b As String
    b = Format(a, "mmmm")
    Dim c As String
    c = Format(a, "yyyy")
    Dim nam As String
    nam = "Archive me " & b & " " & c

    Set objNamespace = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objSourceFolder = Session.Folders("review@vitoshacademy.com").Folders("Posteingang").Folders("InboxX")
    'Set objSourceFolderMAIN = Session.Folders("Archive")

    Set objDestFolder = Session.Folders("Archive").Folders("test1").Folders("test2")

    For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
        DoEvents
        If objVariant.Class = olMail Then
                objVariant.Move objDestFolder
        End If
    Next

    Set objDestFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

It moves the mail to the subfolder without problems. And without checking whether it is at least 2 days old.

Comment: your missing the `intDateDiff ` the rest looks okay + 1