# How can I move Mails Items from Outlook Inbox with specific subject to specific folder/sub folder?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My mails in Outlook has all specific subjects. I have a Excel Sheet which has subject and Folder Name.

I have already this code from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29910853/4539709)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Move_Items()
    '// Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items

    On Error GoTo MsgErr
    '// Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

    '// Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items.Item(lngCount)

        Debug.Print Item.Subject

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            '// Set SubFolder of Inbox
            Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")
            '// Mark As Read
            Item.UnRead = False
            '// Move Mail Item to sub Folder
            Item.Move SubFolder
        End If
    Next lngCount

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
   MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
     & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
     & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
     , vbCritical, "Error!"
  Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub
```

I want the code to read the active sheet columns, as follow:

```
Subject.mail   folder_name
    A                1
    B                2
    C                3
```

For example Mail in the Inbox with subject "A" then it has to place that mail in folder "1".

How do I loop? to look at the Sheet1 and to read to which sub folder it has to move ?

Comment: Did you consider the Outlook mail rules? They can do this for you. You can specify where to move mails with very specific criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options to do this, the painless one is to run Outlook VBA code from inside outlook so you don't need to go through a lot of referencing problem, but at the same time if you are insisting in having your list of subjects and folder in an Excel file, then it is better to run it from Excel, but here is the issue: You'd better not try to run the code from Excel because Microsoft is not supporting that method, so the best way is to write the code in Excel VBA, and again you can do late (runtime) binding or early binding, but I prefer early binding to use intellisence for better referencing outlook objects and avoid late binding performance and/or debugging problems.

Here is the code and how you should use it:

Go to the excel file that you have your subject and folders list or create a new one. Hit ALT+F11 to go to VBE. On the left panel (project explorer) right click and insert a module. Paste this code in there:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MoveEmailsToFolders()
    'arr will be a 2D array sitting in an Excel file, 1st col=subject, 2nd col=folder name
    '   // Declare your Variables
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim strSubjec As String
    Dim strFolder As String

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim Item As Object

    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim arr() As Variant 'store Excel table as an array for faster iterations
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    'On Error GoTo MsgErr

    'Set Excel references
    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    If WS.ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Activesheet did not have the Excel table containing Subjects and Outlook Folder Names", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        arr = WS.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value
        rowCount = UBound(arr, 2)
        If rowCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Excel table does not have rows.", vbCritical, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If


    'Set Outlook Inbox Reference
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

      '   // Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
      For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        strFolder = ""
        Set Item = Items.Item(lngCount)

        'Debug.Print Item.Subject

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            'Determine whether subject is among the subjects in the Excel table
            For i = 1 To rowCount
                If arr(i, 1) = Item.Subject Then
                    strFolder = arr(i, 2)

                    '// Set SubFolder of Inbox, read the appropriate folder name from table in Excel
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(strFolder)
                    '// Mark As Read
                    Item.UnRead = False
                    '// Move Mail Item to sub Folder
                    Item.Move SubFolder
                    Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
            End If

      Next lngCount

  MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
      Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

    Exit Sub

 '// Error information
MsgErr:
    MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
  Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub
```

**Set Reference:**

To use outlook objects, in Excel VBE go to Tools, References and check Microsoft Outlook object library.

**Set Excel Sheet:**

In an Excel sheet, create a table with two columns that the first column contains email subjects and the second column contains folders to which you want those emails to be moved.

Then, insert a shape and right click on that and Assign a Macro, find the name of the macro (MoveEmailsToFolders) and click ok.

**Suggestions:**

You can develop the code more to disregard matchcase. To do that replace this line:

```
arr(i, 1) = Item.Subject
```

with:

```
Ucase(arr(i, 1)) = Ucase(Item.Subject)
```

Also, you can move the emails that contain the subject rather than matching an exact title, for example if an email subject had "test", or begins with "test", or ends with "test", then move it to the corresponding folder. Then, the comparison clause would be:

```
 If arr(i, 1) Like Item.Subject & "*" Then 'begins with
 If arr(i, 1) Like  "*" & Item.Subject & "*" Then 'contains
 If arr(i, 1) Like  "*" & Item.Subject Then 'ends with
```

Hope this helps! Please hit the check mark to make this as the right answer to your questions if it did

Answer (score 0):

I would use an explicit reference to your sheet instead of ActiveSheet unless you are actually running the Macro on a bunch of different sheets. And I'm just assuming your data is in column A and B and starts at row 2 for examples sake. This is how you would loop through your data and trying to match the subject, then move it to a folder with the name in the next column if it matches.

```
If Item.Class = olMail Then

    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = Item.Subject Then
              '// Set SubFolder of Inbox
            Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value)
               '// Mark As Read
            Item.UnRead = False
               '// Move Mail Item to sub Folder
            Item.Move SubFolder
        End If

    Next

End If
```

There are ways you could check without using a loop as well such as the Find method

```
Dim rnFind As Range

If Item.Class = olMail Then

    Set rnFind = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(Item.Subject)

        If Not rnFind Is Nothing Then
              '// Set SubFolder of Inbox
            Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(rnFind.Offset(, 1).Value)
               '// Mark As Read
            Item.UnRead = False
               '// Move Mail Item to sub Folder
            Item.Move SubFolder
        End If

End If
```

Comment: I think the code would not work since the original code is an outlook vba while you mixed it up with excel vba without referencing correctly

Comment: Yeah that's true, I was thinking the VBA was in Excel since he was asking how to do it using Excel data. It would be easy to add a reference to an Excel workbook and have a proper sheet reference in there instead. It would probably be easier to do the entire thing with arrays in VBA anyways, unless there is actually a huge data set of unique e-mail subjects they are trying to categorize like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Do Until IsEmpty loop`**, Make sure to set Excel Object Referees...

See Example on how to loop from Outlook...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Move_Items()
    '// Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim ItemSubject As String
    Dim SubFldr As String
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long

    On Error GoTo MsgErr
    '// Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

    '// Excel Book Reference
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx") ' Excel Book Path

    lngRow = 2 ' Start Row

    With xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Sheet Name

        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(lngRow, 1))
            ItemSubject = .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value ' Subject
            SubFldr = .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value ' Folder Name

            '// Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
            For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set Item = Items.Item(lngCount)

                If Item.Class = olMail Then

                    If Item.Subject = ItemSubject Then

                        Debug.Print Item.Subject
                        Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(SubFldr) ' Set SubFolder

                        Debug.Print SubFolder
                        Item.UnRead = False ' Mark As Read
                        Item.Move SubFolder ' Move to sub Folder

                    End If

                End If
            Next
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
        Loop
    End With

    xlBook.Close

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing

Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
   MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
     & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
     & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
     , vbCritical, "Error!"
  Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub
```