# Is there a way to send excel report receives by email in outlook to a folder automatically?

Tags: excel, outlook

I receive daily excel report via outlook. Is there a way to have the report automatically dragged to a folder on daily bases or when I receive the email ?
Example - Out of stock reports gets to us on daily , I want that excel goes to a specific folder every time automatically .

Thank you,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29910853/4539709

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'




Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    olMail.To = "Jalalbcit@gmail.com"
    olMail.Subject = "Subject Line "
    olMail.Body = "This is the body of the email"
    olMail.Send



End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it throw VBA macros.

```
Outlook - File - Options - Customize Ribbon
```

Tag "Developer". After you can see "Developer" in main menu.

Find in submenu - Visual Basic

In new Project1 click by right mouse button and tap Insert - Module.

Put in open window macros with comments below:

```
Public Sub saveAtt (itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 'var for work with attachments
Dim saveFolder As String 'var for dest folder
Dim sDateMail as string 'var for email date
'save in right format email time
sDateMail = Format(itm.CreationTime, "hh-mm-ss_dd.mm.yyyy")
'set dest folder
saveFolder = "C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\"
'sort all attachments in memail
For each objAtt in itm.Attachments
'save attachment in folder with name: email_date + attachment_filename
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & sDateMail & "_" & objAtt.FileName
'clear var for work with attachments
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next objAtt
End Sub
```

Save by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd>.

After that you need to Create Rule for target email.

Comment: Thank thank you IonPAX ,   Is there a way to specify which email to take it from - the email always have the same subject and coming from same sender "

Comment: macros just helps to you save attachment in destination folder. You can set all sorts and filters  by Outlook service "Creating Rule" for incoming emails.