# Outlook sometimes crashes when sending mail using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have VBA code in Excel to perform the following actions:

1. retrieve order request
2. pull SAP reports
3. validate order request
4. connect to SAP to do transaction
5. send email
6. loop (from #4) until all orders are done

The sending email part crashes probably 15% of the time on replying to the second email.  I can continue the automation flow by acknowledging the below error, restart Outlook, and the script continues like nothing happened.

[image]

I'm thinking that it might be a memory issue with this particular bot as it's only this one that fails.  I do comprehend that after the the code hits `End Sub`, then all the variables should be cleared from memory.

The code is only for replying.  It gets called after the SAP transaction is done.

```vb
Sub EmailReply()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Call OpeningDuties
    
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oLNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim topOlFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oLMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Dim EmailAddress As Object
    
    Dim fdr_Unprocessed As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim fdr_Pending As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim fdr_Processed As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    
    Set myNameSpace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("mapi")
    Set objOwner = myNameSpace.CreateRecipient("retailrma@company.com")
    objOwner.Resolve
    
    If objOwner.Resolved Then
        Set topOlFolder = myNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
    End If
    
    Set fdr_Unprocessed = topOlFolder.Folders("RMA - Unprocessed")
    Set fdr_Pending = topOlFolder.Folders("RMA - Pending")
    Set fdr_Processed = topOlFolder.Folders("RMA - Processed")
    
    For Each oLMail In fdr_Unprocessed.Items
    
        If (oLMail.Subject = Range("Email_Subject").Text And Format(oLMail.ReceivedTime, "Medium Time") = Format(Range("Email_Date").Text, "Medium Time") And oLMail.SenderEmailAddress = Range("Email_Address").Text) _
          Or (oLMail.Subject = Range("Email_Subject").Text And Format(oLMail.ReceivedTime, "Medium Time") = Format(Range("Email_Date").Text, "Medium Time")) Then
     
            'if email can be found then reply email  or send email
        
            'Define copy range on Email Template sheet as a word document
            Dim CopyRange As Range
        
            'Set wdDoc = oLMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        
            'Determining if the email should be responded in English or French
            If Range("email_language") = "En" Then
            
                FirstRow = 3
                FirstColumn = 3
                LastRow = 246
                LastColumn = 9
    
            ElseIf Range("email_language") = "Fr" Then
    
                FirstRow = 3
                FirstColumn = 11
                LastRow = 246
                LastColumn = 16
    
            End If
        
            Sheets("Email Template").Select
            Sheets("Email Template").Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Show"
        
            Set ReplyAll = oLMail.ReplyAll
            Set EmailAddress = Range("Email_Address")
            Set CopyRange = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            'Error handling if no email address
            If EmailAddress = 0 Then
                RMAStatus = "Non valid email address"
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        
            With ReplyAll
                .To = EmailAddress
                .CC = "retailrma@company.com"
                .Display
                .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                Set wdDoc = oLMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
                CopyRange.Copy
                wdDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting  'pastes the approved / non approved IMEIs into outlook reply email
                .Send
            End With
        
            'move email to processed folder
            oLMail.Move fdr_Processed
        
            'Resets Email Template
            Sheets("Email Template").Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=1
        
            GoTo ExitSendEmail
        
        End If
        
    Next oLMail
    
ExitSendEmail:
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `Sheets("Email Template").Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=1` is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet). You need to qualify the worksheet for the inner `Cells` calls.

Comment: What do you mean by "Outlook crashes"? That you see a runtime error? Or does Outlook app die?

Comment: You have different variable names `Dim oLNameSpace` vs `Set myNameSpace`. From this I speculate that you're not using `Option Explicit`. You should --- it can alert you to problems in your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779782/how-to-move-each-emails-from-inbox-to-a-sub-folder

Comment: @xidgel The Outlook app dies which causes the VBA code to hang waiting for the next action.  It's not a run time error within the VBA script.  I'm not using Option Explicit for this particular code module but i'll add it.  I'll also take a look at the different types of variables used and get back with my findings...

Comment: Can you comment out the PasteAndFormat  and see if the error still occurs?

Comment: @xidgel TY for pointing this out.  I have made updates to the object declarations

Comment: @dmitry I will focus on the copy / paste sections of my code if the other provided suggestions do not work.  I also might need to use a HTML body type of email so the way I'm pasting the results into the email might also have to change...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that all objects are defined correctly in the code:

```
Dim oLNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
```

But later in the code another object is used:

```
 Set myNameSpace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("mapi")
```

Another possible weak area is a Word object model used for editing emails.

```
Set wdDoc = oLMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
```

Try to use the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171418(v=office.11))  property of the `MailItem` class instead.

Also you may add a delay between each iteration. See the [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function) function for more information. The following example uses the `Timer` function to pause the application. The example also uses `DoEvents` to yield to other processes during the pause.

```
Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime
If (MsgBox("Press Yes to pause for 5 seconds", 4)) = vbYes Then
    PauseTime = 5    ' Set duration.
    Start = Timer    ' Set start time.
    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes.
    Loop
    Finish = Timer    ' Set end time.
    TotalTime = Finish - Start    ' Calculate total time.
    MsgBox "Paused for " & TotalTime & " seconds"
Else
    End
End If
```

Comment: I have update my code with 1. cleaning up object definitions 2. added a 1 sec pause after each loop iteration 3. added the DoEvents code.  I ran a test batch with the new updates with  no issues.  I will monitor for a few days and report back if provided suggestions worked.  TY for your detailed recommendations.

Comment: The last resort is to avoid the Word object model - use the `HTMLBody` property for setting up the message body.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions as they have resolved my Outlook app crashing issue.  This bot has been running for over a week without experiencing any issues.  I'll keep in mind of do events and adding pauses to my automation!