# how to remove all attachment in outlook

Tags: vb.net

first i use this code for delete the all attachment in outlook

```
 For i = 1 To oMail.Attachments.Count

      oMail.Attachments.Remove(i)

 Next
```

i have 4 attachment it remove but i check the `oMail.Attachments.Count` it display 2

After i search in stack forum this code

```
For Each a As outlook.Attachment In oMail.Attachments

   a.Delete()

Next
```

it delete the 1 & 3 attachment but not delete the 2 & 4 attachment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For Each loop: Some items get skipped when looping through Outlook mailbox to delete items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/for-each-loop-some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox-to-de)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below;

```
If oMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

  For i = oMail.Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1

   ' Delete the attachment.
   oMail.Attachments.Item(i).Delete

  Next i
  oMail.Save

End If
```

This [LINK](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=70) might give you some more details.