# VBA Outlook Array Index out of bounds

Tags: arrays, vba, outlook, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following code to automatically delete emails that are older than two months:

```
Sub RemoveAutomaticItemsInDeletedItems()

    If MsgBox("Delete items from from Deleted Items folder ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then

        Dim oDeletedItems As Outlook.Folder
        Dim obj As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim i As Integer

        'Obtain a reference to deleted items folder
        Set oDeletedItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
        For i = 1 To oDeletedItems.Items.Count - 1
         If oDeletedItems.Items(i).Class = olMail Then
          Set obj = oDeletedItems.Items.Item(i)
           If obj.ReceivedTime <= DateAdd("m", -2, Now) Then

             'Deleting them
             Debug.Print obj.SenderEmailAddress
             'Debug.Print obj.Subject

              obj.Delete

          End If
         End If
        Next
        MsgBox "Items have been deleted"
    End If

End Sub
```

However, the error:

`Array index out of bounds`

is continually called on the line:

`If oDeletedItems.Items(i).Class = olMail Then`

using `Debug.Print` I have looked into the line of code just above that: `oDeletedItems.Items.Count - 1`, and the count is 1889 thus there are elements in the array.

Why would this error persist if there are objects within the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For Each loop: Some items get skipped when looping through Outlook mailbox to delete items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/for-each-loop-some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox-to-de)

Answer (score 2):

The act of deleting an item decrements `Items.Count` and takes it out of sync with the current value if `i`.

Loop backwards so that `i` is always the last item (which is guaranteed to exist):

```
For i = oDeletedItems.Items.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
```