# Compare two Outlook folders to filter emails not in second folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I've come across several email filtering solution but couldn't solve my problem using those ideas.

How do I compare two Outlook folders and based on the first folder filter out the emails not in the second folder according to `SentOn` or `ReceiveTime` and copy those mails to the second folder?

I can get the mails in both folders using `If sMail.SentOn = dMail.SentOn`.
If I alter the condition to `If sMail.SentOn <> dMail.SentOn` it is not working.

```vb
Sub FindMails()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Folder
    Dim olFolder2 As Folder
        
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.Folders.Item("hayat_archive_Loc").Folders.Item("Inbox")
    Set olFolder2 = olNS.Folders.Item("Xhayat_archive_Loc").Folders.Item("Inbox")

    For Each sMail In olFolder.Items
        For Each dMail In olFolder2.Items
            If sMail.SentOn <> dMail.SentOn Then
                Debug.Print sMail.SentOn & vbTab & sMail.Subject
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**Debug Output `If sMail.SentOn = dMail.SentOn`**

```
9/9/2017 12:27:34 PM    Access Problem
9/9/2017 9:07:33 AM     Report on 08-Sep-2017.
9/9/2017 6:39:51 AM     Handover of 08th September, 2017
```

**Debug Output `If sMail.SentOn <> dMail.SentOn`**

```
9/9/2017 12:38:36 PM    Access Problem
9/9/2017 12:38:36 PM    Access Problem
9/9/2017 12:38:36 PM    Access Problem
9/9/2017 12:27:34 PM    Access Problem
9/9/2017 12:27:34 PM    Access Problem
9/9/2017 9:10:13 AM     Egress (09-September-2017)
9/9/2017 9:10:13 AM     Egress (09-September-2017)
9/9/2017 9:10:13 AM     Egress (09-September-2017)
9/9/2017 9:07:33 AM     Report on 08-Sep-2017.
9/9/2017 9:07:33 AM     Report on 08-Sep-2017.
9/9/2017 7:23:41 AM     Password reset
9/9/2017 7:23:41 AM     Password reset
9/9/2017 7:23:41 AM     Password reset
9/9/2017 7:04:55 AM     Report on 08-Sep-2017.
9/9/2017 7:04:55 AM     Report on 08-Sep-2017.
9/9/2017 7:04:55 AM     Report on 08-Sep-2017.
9/9/2017 6:39:51 AM     Handover of 08th September, 2017
9/9/2017 6:39:51 AM     Handover of 08th September, 2017
9/9/2017 2:45:18 AM     Usages report on 07th September , 2017
9/9/2017 2:45:18 AM     Usages report on 07th September , 2017
9/9/2017 2:45:18 AM     Usages report on 07th September , 2017
```

Comment: You say "its not working" but do not say how it is not working.

Comment: I would not use `Restul` and `MsgBox` as you have. I would replace `Restul = Restul & sMail.Subject & vbCrLf` with `Debug.Print sMail.Subject`. `Debug.Print` outputs to the Immediate Window which you can study at your leisure or use Copy & Paste to transfer its contents elsewhere. You cannot do either with `MsgBox`.  The Immediate Window will accept 200 or so lines before the oldest lines are lost. If 200 is not enough I will show you how to output to a file.

Comment: I would not rely on a single date as the match between two emails.  It is unlikely that two emails are sent within the same second but it is possible. I would check Sender, Recipients, HtmlBody, Body and any other property I cared about to be absolutely certain the emails were identical.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thanks, I will use Debug.Print, would you show me some hints to use all of those validating points to write a proper function , I am a beginner here ,

Comment: Also my main focus for this question was why `If sMail.SentOn <> dMail.SentOn` was not working, `Debug.Print` return same as msgbox in this case. Which is, it suppose to return emails those are not same `SentOn` in both folder, But rather it return each emails multiple times .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially I got answer for this question from this post:

[Check and Copy all emails from source folder those are not existed in destination folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135228/4450048)

Answered by: [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams)

```
Sub CopyMail(SourceFolder As Outlook.Folder, DestinationFolder As Outlook.Folder)
Dim sMail As Object
Dim dMail As Object
Dim MailC As Object
Dim dictSent As New Scripting.dictionary, i As Long

'get a list of all unique sent times in the
'  destination folder
For Each dMail In DestinationFolder.Items
    dictSent(dMail.SentOn) = True
Next

'loop through the source folder and copy all items where
'  the sent time is not in the list
For i = SourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set sMail = SourceFolder.Items(i)

    If Not dictSent.Exists(sMail.SentOn) Then
        Set MailC = sMail.Copy        'copy and move
        MailC.Move DestinationFolder
        dictSent(sMail.SentOn) = True 'add to list
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `Debug.print dMail.Subject` instead of `sMail.Subject`

This will give you your answer.