# Search sent mail and move multiple mail to a folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I try to search the SentMail folder for mail where To address ends with, lets say .cn and move it to a personal folder.

The code work but doesn't move all the mail, for every time I run it it's take a few more mail.

If I have 24 mails that ends with .cn it  takes 13,6,3,2 so in the end it finds all the mail but not on the same run.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
Sub Search_SentMail()

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim MyNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim MyInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object

Set MyNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MyInbox = MyNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myOutbox = MyNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set myitems = myOutbox.Items

Dim junk As Outlook.Folder
Set junk = MyNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set junk = junk.Folders("CN")
Count = 0
For Each myItem In myitems
If TypeOf myItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
If Right(myItem.To, 4) = ".cn'" Then
myItem.Move junk
Count = Count + 1
End If
End If
Next myItem

Debug.Print Count
Set MyNameSpace = Nothing
Set MyInbox = Nothing
Set myOutbox = Nothing
Set myitems = Nothing
Set junk = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So you assume that chinese are spammers, right? ;-) Add this before the loop on `myitems`, and retry : `myitems.sort "[ReceivedTime]"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For Each loop: Some items get skipped when looping through Outlook mailbox to delete items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/for-each-loop-some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox-to-de)

Comment: When moving items or deleting items in a collection either loop in reverse or process item 1 until there are no more items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was here:
[For Each loop: Some items get skipped when looping through Outlook mailbox to delete items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/for-each-loop-some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox-to-de)

Thanks @niton